# Как убрать галочку

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Как убрать галочку с чекбокса с помощью JavaScript, которую установил пользователь?

Comment: Очень абстрактный вопрос. В каком случае он эту галку установил, она установлена по умолчанию, устанавливается по событию?

Comment: Установить свойство checked = false;

Comment: Она устанавливается по событию

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('yourCheckbox').checked = false
```